# Get Route Values in Razor Pages

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-routing, razor-pages

I want to know how can I get the route values in Razor Pages (Page.cshtml).
Ex.
`https://localhost:44320/AdminPanel/Admins`
if I was using MVC i would get these datas as

```
var controller = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"]; //AdminPanel
var action = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"]; //Admins
```

How can i get these values in Razor Pages?

For anyone trying to get it you can get it by:

```
var fullRoute = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Page"]; // AdminPanel/Admin
```

Comment: You do not have a controller in the razor pages.  What specifically are you trying to get ?

Comment: @Shyju I am trying to get that value `Admins` or the full route `AdminPanel/Admins` in page. I tried it and i found that i could get that `AdminPanel/Admins` by `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Page"];`

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have a page named `AdminPanel.cshtml` in your `Pages` folder, add a parameter after `@page` on the first line, like this:

`@page "{action}"`

Then in the code behind (`AdminPanel.cshtml.cs`), add a prop and a parameter to your `OnGet` method like so:

```
private string _action;

public void OnGet(string action) {
  _action = action; //now do whatever you want with it
}
```

You can add a getter if you want to access it in your model back on the cshtml page.

**Note:** doing the above will make that page require an action be specified. Alternatively, you can also make it optional by adding a question mark (`@page "{action?}"`) and setting a default value in your OnGet (`OnGet(string action="")`).